# Parent Styling removed when using styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Hi I am trying to use styled component to render my html design. However, I am facing a problem that my styling is removed in the parent tags when I enter the new styled tag. It only keeps the styling of the innermost tag and removes everything. A prompt reply would be appreciated. Sorry for not sharing the import link of the Elevation comoponent due to company restrictions

```
    import styled from "styled-components";


const AllGroupWrapper = Elevation.extend`
    width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 32px;
`;

const TableHeadingBlockWrapper = styled.div`
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight:
`;
const AllGroupListHeading = styled.div`
  font-size: 10px;
`;

const AllGroupSearch = styled(OpenSearch)`
  width: 324px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 24px;
`;


<AllGroupWrapper level={3}>
    <TableHeadingBlockWrapper>{`My List (20)`}</TableHeadingBlockWrapper>
    <AllGroupSearch/>
</AllGroupWrapper>
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Hi Karthik, This is creating a problem when i am trying to extend a component already declared. However, if i use normal styled.div it is rendering properly.

Comment: this code looks okay.

Comment: the styling provided in the .extend are erased when i am deploying this code. Is there any work around that the parent styling does not get erased in the above case